# Use regex in linux kernel

Tags: c, regex, linux-kernel

I would like to use regexes in a linux kernel module.
I have the regexes ready, and I tested them in user space with `regex.h`.

I know that `regex.h` is a user space library, but is there a kernel alternative?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I am trying to find C code in SMTP connections for a university project.

Comment: Edit your question to explain what is your kernel module doing and why it and what for is using regexes.

Comment: Porting a exist library from user-space to kernel-space? It should't be very hard.  `kernel-source/lib` directory contains lots of library that you can refer to.

Comment: You don't need a kernel module to inspect SMTP data. `iptables` should be enough (to e.g. redirect SMTP to some user process at the kernel level)

Comment: To whomever cast the close vote, he isn't asking for a recommendation for a library. He's asking what to do use regexps in the kernel. The answer is to use the kernel regexp feature. Suggesting he's asking for a recommendation for a library indicates rather indicates a presumption the questioner is in the wrong without considering what he's asking.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I presume he is trying to filter the contents of the packets - see 'trying to find C code in SMTP connections' as opposed to 'trying to find SMTP connections'.

Comment: I understood that too, but OP don't need a kernel module for this. He just needs to master `iptables` and have a user process doing the filtering. In addition, many SMTP servers (e.g. [exim](http://exim.org/) ...) have extensive filtering abilities. No need to add extra brittle code inside the kernel!

Comment: Sure, but filtering in kernel space is much faster as it doesn't require context switches, so isn't an inherently bad idea. As OP says, he wants to do it in kernel space - how is a reasonable question.

Comment: I don't want to do it in kernel space, this is the project demand :P lol

Comment: It is a legitimate question, regardless of whether or not the actual thing he's trying to do should be done in the kernel. There are legitimate cases where you might want to do regular expression matching inside the kernel (namely the kernel tracing subsystem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel already has a regexp engine; the functions are declared in [kernel/trace/trace.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/trace/trace.h#L1019). It is part of the linux trace framework, and could relatively easily be adapted. You can see where it is currently used [(identifier search)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=regex).

Note also someone has got there before you. [The `l7-filter` kernel component](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/) classifies L7 traffic based on (inter-alia) regex matching the packets. Their regex implementation has [a man page](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/V8regex).

You could also pass the packets to userspace via a socket using [`libipq`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man3/libipq.3.html), classify them, and pass them back. This is an easier approach, but slower, and apparently isn't what you want (but might be useful to another reader).

Comment: I get this error while compiling: `fatal error: kernel/trace/trace.h: No such file or directory`
I did `#include <kernel/trace/trace.h>`. is it wrong? (I am new to kernel programming :( )

Comment: Looks like your include paths are wrong. Make sure you can build a simple kernel module that does very little before trying to use regexps. Building kernel modules is not as simple as building standalone programs. Also note the regexp framework might not be exported or may be exported GPL only in which case you'll either have to build a custom kernel or set the GPL export stuff up. That's one of things your project will be trying to teach you.

Comment: This is not a regex engine. It's a shell-style `glob` pattern matching (in fact the same as given in the answer of Mayank R). It has a relatively bad time complexity ‒ `lenth(text)*length(pattern)` ‒ which makes it unsuitable for real-world network packet detection / filtering. See [1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/trace/trace_events_filter.c#L862), [2](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/trace/trace_events_filter.c#L821) and [3](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/trace/trace_events_filter.c#L797).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need simple pattern matching, you could also use the glob match function.

```
bool __pure glob_match(char const *pat, char const *str)
```

Here is the manpage for what it can support:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html

Here is the function definition in kernel code:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/glob.c

You would need to include the header file `"linux/glob.h"` for it.

Answer (score 0):

The linux kernel doesn't have real regex functions. It only has functions to handle '*' in strings.

The [l7-filter kernel component](http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/) provides regex functions but its match function has recursive form, which is not suitable for the kernel with small stack.

Your best bet is [kpcre kernel component](https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre/), which supports stack-free just-in-time compilation. It provides POSIX regex functions as well as PCRE(perl compatible regular expression) functions.